# Finding the average from the last 14 days in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I would like to figure out a formula that will look at the last 14 days of data in column D and calculate the average. But I would like it to dynamically update every day so it's always showing the last 14 days average based on the current date.

Does that make sense? Is this possible?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C8paoYXirR5qus8axs-SciRqxeaBWMxsSmC0PGX969E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: average including DIV/0 errors as zero? or excluding them?

Comment: Excluding them, sorry I should have mentioned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY({A2:D}, 
 "select Col4 
  where Col4 is not null 
  order by toDate(Col1) desc 
  limit 14", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much!